# How do I send progress streams using Node and Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-sent-events

I am making a Video Resizer site and I need to send the video conversion progress to the user. I read about SSE but all tutorials use get request and listen through EventSource.
In my case it is post request which contains the video file to be resized.

My Server Side Code is

```
const resizeVideo = async (req, res) => {
    const command = ffmpeg(path.join(rootPath, 'uploads', 'videos', 'v.mp4'));
    command.size('?x480').keepDAR().on('end', () => {
        res.end();
        console.log("Converted");
    }).on('progress', function (progress) {
        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done');
// I want to send this progress updates to react.js client.
    }).save(path.join(rootPath, 'output', '1.mp4'));
}
```

My Client Side code is

```
 setIsUploading(true);
        const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization'
            },
        };

        const response = await instance.post('videoconvert/resize', formData, config);

//I want to get updates here.

        setIsUploading(false);
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Kedar, this tutorial might be of use to you if you are still working on it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-server-sent-events-build-realtime-app

Answer (score 0):

you cant use axios you need to use SocketIO to send update live

Comment: Can't SSE be used in this scenario?